# consume secure web service asmx in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, wsdl

I want to consume secured web service in asp.net mvc, I need to create proxy class to this service 
I tried to use wsdl.exe tool but it gave me the following errors
There was an error downloading 
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized. 
is there another way to create proxy class 
or there  is another technique to call this secured web service in my application

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the WSDL requires authentication in order to be downloaded. I suppose the Web Service also. The [WSDL.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) utility allows you to specify the username and password to be used when downloading the WSDL. So go ahead, talk to the author of the web service to understand what account you need to use in order to access it and then try the `/username` and `/password` parameters:

```
wsdl.exe /username:john /password:secret http://example.com/foo.asmx?WSDL
```

Comment: thank you Darin for your response I tried pass username and password in wsdl command and it gave me the same errors , but I can  access the service by browser by giving user name and password, so where is the problem please

Comment: What kind of authentication does the service use? Is it Windows authentication? If so you might need to specify the DOMAIN as well using the `/domain` parameter: `wsdl.exe /username:john /password:secret /domain:YOURCOMPANY http://example.com/foo.asmx?WSDL`

Comment: thanks Darin, I add domain name but still gave me the same errors , I don't know why, is there another technique to consume this secure service in my application please